# Error when submitting modals Discord "Something went wrong. Try again."

Tags: node.js, discord.js, modal-dialog

When someone clicks submit on a modal the modal gives an error "Something went wrong. Try again." I would like to try an avoid this error. I have tried to do some research but have not been able to find anything to resolve this.

[image]

Submit File

```
const { execute } = require("../selectMenus/Ticketwizard");

module.exports = {
  data: {
    name: `GeneralTicket`,
  },
  async execute(interaction, client, message) {
    client.on("interactionCreate", (modalSubmit) => {
      if (!modalSubmit.isModalSubmit()) return;

      const a1 = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("a1");
      const a2 = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("a2");
      const a3 = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("a3");

      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0x0099ff)
        .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.user.tag}` ,iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
        .setTitle("ClixMC General Support Ticket ")
        .setTimestamp()
        .addFields(
          { name: "IGN:", value: `${a1}` },
          { name: "What is your Ticket related to:", value: `${a2}` },
          { name: "Brief summary:", value: `${a3}` }
        );

      const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
        new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId("GT1")
          .setLabel(`Submit`)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
          .setDisabled(false)
      );

      modalSubmit.update({
        embeds: [embed],
        ephemeral: true,
        components: [row],
        content:
          "To submit your ticket click `Submit` to cancel click `Dismiss Message`.",
      });
      module.exports = embed;
    });
  },
};
```

Questions File:

```
module.exports = {
  data: {
    name: `Ticketwizard`,
  },
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    if (!interaction.isStringSelectMenu()) return;
    const selected = interaction.values[0];
    const wait = require("node:timers/promises").setTimeout;

    if (selected === "1") {
      const modal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId("GeneralTicket")
        .setTitle("ClixMC General Support!");

      const a1 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("a1")
        .setLabel("What is your Minecraft IGN?")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

      const a2 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("a2")
        .setLabel("What area of ClixMC is your ticket related?")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

      const a3 = new TextInputBuilder()
        .setCustomId("a3")
        .setLabel("Provide a brief summary of your request.")
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);

      const a9999 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(a1);
      const a99999 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(a2);
      const a999999 = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(a3);

      modal.addComponents(a9999, a99999, a999999);
      await interaction.showModal(modal);

      } else if (selected === "2") { //ect
```

I am not to sure what else to try or look for.
Thank you to anyone that is able to help.

Comment: Why do you create a new event listener every time someone calls the command? Why do you have a `module.exports` inside `module.exports`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I am using that same embed in another file. As far as I am aware that is the only way for me to export that embed so it can be used in another file